# Naming a variable `current` in a kernel module leads to "function declaration isn’t a prototype" error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linux-kernel

I'm learning to write kernel modules for linux as a beginner. What I'm trying to do is to write every task and its child process into the kernel log using DFS algorithm. But when I compile the code using `Makefile`, it shows the above error:

```
function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Werror=strict-prototypes]
struct task_struct *current;
```

It points out the `task_struct` keyword at the function DFS. 
Here's my code:

```
# include <linux/init.h>
# include <linux/kernel.h>
# include <linux/module.h>
# include <linux/sched.h>
# include <linux/list.h>

void DFS (struct task_struct *task)
{
    struct task_struct *current;
    struct list_head *list;

    list_for_each (list, &task->children)
    {
        current = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
        printk(KERN_INFO "%d\t%d\t%s \n", (int)current->state, current->pid, current->comm);

        if (current != NULL)
        {
            DFS(current);
        }
    }
}

int DFS_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading the Second Module...\n");

    printk(KERN_INFO "State\tPID\tName\n");

    DFS(&init_task);   

    return 0;
}

void DFS_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing the Second Module...\n");
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this ??

Comment: In the kernel, `current` is a globally visible variable (pointer) pointing to the current process-table-entry.

Comment: To elaborate on what @wildplasser said... on x86, `current` is actually `#define`d to a function: `get_current()`. Hence, after preprocessing, your declaration devolved to: `struct task_struct *get_current();` which offended the `strict-prototypes` directive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kernel has a macro called `current` which is pointing to users currently executing process. As [this book](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch02.html) states,

> The current pointer refers to the user process currently executing. During the execution of a system call, such as open or read, the current process is the one that invoked the call.

In other words, as @GilHamilton mentioned in the comments, `current` is `#define`d to the function `get_current()` in the kernel. Using `current` as a variable name will give a compile-time error!

Comment: Um... If `current` were a variable, using it in your code would not result in any errors. Why would it? The whole point here is that `current` is not a variable, it is actually a *macro*.

Comment: @AnT Well I'm not a pro in this. But renaming the variable name resolved my problem. So it seems like the error is in the variable name, `current`. (Does the name `current` has anything to do in a __Kernal Module__ ?)

Comment: The question has been clearly answered in the comments by Gil Hamilton in August of 2015 and you thanked him for the answer. In November 2015 you suddenly provided your own answer that completey ignored (and contradicted) that previous information (?). And now, in 2017, you are asking if there's anyhting named `current` in kernel module???

Comment: I found these information in a book (as I mentioned in my answer). I thanked them for the information. But those _Information_ wasn't posted as an answer. So I posted it as an answer. I didn't thought it is a bad practice.