# function declaration isn't prototype

Tags: c, linux

I get an error, that function declaration isn't prototype, 
field "get_current" declared as a function

But I have no `get_current` field at all in my code.

```
#ifndef FILESFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FILESFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

#define NB_MAX_TRANSITIONS 20
#define FILE_NAME_SIZE 25

typedef struct Page_Descriptor Page_Descriptor;
typedef struct Transition Transition;
typedef struct Transitions_Graph Transitions_Graph;
typedef struct File_Descriptor File_Descriptor;
typedef struct File_Descriptors_List File_Descriptors_List;

//La liste des descripteurs de fichier
struct File_Descriptors_List{
  File_Descriptor* head;// Pointeur vers le premier élement de la liste.
  File_Descriptor* current;
  unsigned int nbFiles; // nombre de descripteurs de fichier dans la liste.
};

// La structure descripteur de fichier.
struct File_Descriptor
{
  char* file_name; // Nom du fichier
  Transitions_Graph* transition_graph; // le graphe de transition des pages.
  File_Descriptor* next; // pointeur vers le prochaine fichier dans la liste.
};

//Le graphe des transitions
struct Transitions_Graph{
  Page_Descriptor* head; // le premier noeud du graphe de transitions.
  Page_Descriptor* current_page; // la dernière page utilisée dans le graphe.
};

// Le descripteur qui contient les informations sur chaque page.
struct Page_Descriptor
{
  //int page_number; // Identifiant de la page
  int page_offset; // Offset de la page
  int nb_From_Transitions;// Le nombre des transitions à partir de cette page
  int visited; //Etat de la page dans le parcours de l'affichage pour eviter le repassage sur la même page.
  Transition* next_transitions;// Vecteur qui contient des pointeurs vers les pages suivantes
  int index_Transition_Table;//Le nombre de pages suivantes.
};

// La definition d'une transition d'une page à une autre.
struct Transition
{
    int nb_To_Transitions;//number of transitions to this page
    Page_Descriptor* next_page;
};
#endif // FILESFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

I have no Idea about what's going on, because I had it working on codeBlocks on Windows, but not when compiling with gcc in linux.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7p9k.png]

Comment: Why not paste the code here?

Comment: I have the code on a virtual machine, so I prefered taking a screenshot :p

Comment: @KaciHyou well, we don't prefer dealing with screenshots, and you didn't even include one (just a link).

Comment: Users here prefer to see the code pasted, and that is why all these down + close votes :P

Comment: I do not see something called `get_current` in your code.

Comment: @KaciHyou This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157741/function-declaration-isn-t-a-prototype-in-c

Comment: @mch that's the problem, I have no get_current and yet it appears in the error message

Comment: Follow the link provided by @akhilesh1988-- that looks very promising.

Comment: fixed thank you :D @akh

Comment: @KaciHyou-- you might add your `#include`s to your question post so others can see where the problem `#define current` came from.

Answer (score 1):

In the header file `asm/current.h`, the function `get_current()` is defined, and then the `current` macro is `#define`d:

```
#define current get_current()
```

This header file is itself an `#include` in the `linux/sched.h` header file. You have not provided a list of your `#include` files, but I suspect that you have this header file as an `#include`, either directly or indirectly.

You need to change `current` in this line of your program:

```
File_Descriptor* current;
```

to avoid the unwanted macro expansion.